# ejabberd external authentication failure..extauth script has exitted abruptly with reason 'normal'

Tags: ejabberd

I am using external authentication in ejabberd authentication. I am using python script but unable to authenticate the users from my database MySQL. I am getting error as "@extauth:loop:143 extauth script has exited abruptly with reason 'normal' " in my ejabberd.log file. Don't know why its not authenticating.Please give your suggestions...Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the Mysql native module in ejabberd ? External authentication is using Erlang base protocol and is a bit tricky to get right.

Comment: For your information, the Erlang port protocol is documented here: http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/guide/index.html#authentication

Comment: Thanks Mickael...I tried with mysql native module which is available in ejabberd.yml file.Through mysql module i am able to connect to mysql database and i am able to authenticate users from ejabberd users table.. But this module is not allowing to authenticate users from other databases in mysql..That is why i switched to external authentication.

Comment: I have to authenticate the users from different database present in mysql.i am not supposed to use ejabberd database for authentication..

Comment: Then you can use the MySQL module and adapt it to your schema. If you go with external authentication, then you need to troubleshoot implementation of the Erlang port protocol in your script as shown in the documentation, I guess. you did not share your actual script so I do not think anyone can give you good feedback.